# Get compiled css from a less file

Tags: html, css, less

I have one less file which in turn imports multiple less files. Is there a way to get entire compiled css from that less life ? Which I can reference in an html file?

Comment: see http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's basically how less is *always* used.

Assuming your main less file is called `styles.less`, you'd run:

```
lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

to get the combined results.

See http://lesscss.org/#using-less for more details and options.